# Javascript type error - The "listener" argument must be of type Function. Received type object

Tags: javascript, node.js, addeventlistener

I am trying to create a URL shortener using jsonbase.com and vanilla javascript.

1. button tag in HTML was not able to recognize the method "shortUrl" from my js file. So, I directly added the code of add event listener in the js file.

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
            <input type="url" id="urlinput">
                <input id="mybutton" type="button" value="Short the URL"/>
            </input>
        </div>
        <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
```

2. Now, I am getting an error - *Javascript type error - The "listener" argument must be of type Function. Received type object* - when I am trying to use jsonbase.com for storing the data.

**script.js**

```
function shortUrl() {
  var longurl = getURL();
  genHash();
  var uniqueHash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
  sendRequest(longurl, uniqueHash);

  if (window.location.hash !== "") {
    var short = getRequest(uniqueHash);
    if (short !== "") {
      window.location.herf = "short";
    }
  }
}
```

**use of jsonbase.com**

```
var jsonbase = require("jsonbase.com");
var token = "mytoken";
var store = jsonbase(token);
var endpoint = `jsonbase.com/${token}`;

//sending request
function sendRequest(longURL, uniqueHash) {
  store.write(`${endpoint}/${uniqueHash}`, longURL);
}

//getting request
function getRequest(uniqueHash) {
  return store.read(`${endpoint}/${uniqueHash}`).then((response) => {
    return response.data;
  });
}
```

generating hash for shorter

```
function genHash() {
  if (window.location.hash === "") {
    window.location.hash = getRandomStr();
  }
}
```

**Error screenshot -**
[image: error screenshot]

I have created a reproducible sample code sandbox for my private application - https://codesandbox.io/s/url-shortner-t3ov2

Please let me know if any more info is required.

Comment: On which line the error occurs?

Comment: Added the details

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not your code, the issue is the package not parsing the JSON correctly, try using a different package

**I know this does not answer your question, but it should solve it**